# How to set total number of rows before an OFFSET occurs in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure that filters and paginates for a DataTable.

**Problem**: I need to set an `OUTPUT` variable for `@TotalRecords` found before an `OFFSET` occurs, otherwise it sets `@TotalRecord` to `@RecordPerPage`.

I've messed around with CTE's and also simply trying this:

```
SELECT *, @TotalRecord = COUNT(1)
FROM dbo
```

But that doesn't work either.

Here is my stored procedure, with most of the stuff pulled out:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchErrorReports]
    @FundNumber varchar(50) = null,
    @ProfitSelected bit = 0,

    @SortColumnName varchar(30) = null,
    @SortDirection varchar(10) = null,
    @StartIndex int = 0,
    @RecordPerPage int = null,

    @TotalRecord INT = 0 OUTPUT  --NEED TO SET THIS BEFORE OFFSET!
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT *
    FROM 
        (SELECT *
         FROM dbo.View
         WHERE (@ProfitSelected = 1 AND Profit = 1)) AS ERP
    WHERE   
        ((@FundNumber IS NULL OR @FundNumber = '') 
         OR (ERP.FundNumber LIKE '%' + @FundNumber + '%'))
    ORDER BY      
        CASE 
           WHEN @SortColumnName = 'FundNumber' AND @SortDirection = 'asc' 
              THEN ERP.FundNumber 
        END ASC,
        CASE 
           WHEN @SortColumnName = 'FundNumber' AND @SortDirection = 'desc' 
              THEN ERP.FundNumber 
        END DESC
        OFFSET @StartIndex ROWS 
           FETCH NEXT @RecordPerPage ROWS ONLY
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you need to know the number of rows that'll be returned *before* you run the query? The only way you could do that would be to perform a `COUNT(*)` and *hope* the underlying data doesn't change. Why not get the number of rows afterwards using `@@ROWCOUNT`?

Comment: @Larnu Not before I run the query but before an Offset/Fetch occurs otherwise it returns the value of @RecordPerPage. So I just tried ```SET @TotalRecord = @@ROWCOUNT;``` after the Offset/Fetch and it returned 1 row (13 rows were expected)

Comment: *"Not before I run the query but before an Offset/Fetch occurs"* that makes no sense. `OFFSET`/`FETCH` is *part* of that query. If `@@ROWCOUNT` returned `1` that means that 1 row was returned in the prior statement; so if 13 rows weren't returned it's because your query isn't doing what you *think* it is.

Comment: Perhaps you'll be better off providing sample data and expected results; right now what you describe and the comments simply logically don't make any sense. You're describing that you want to do something in the middle of a `SELECT` statement, and you can't do that. It is a single statement, you can't do something "in the middle" of it; it needs to complete first.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry I meant to write ```SET @TotalRecord = @@ROWCOUNT;``` returns 5. So if ```@RecordPerPage``` is set to 10 for example; ```SET @TotalRecord = @@ROWCOUNT;``` returns 10. And if the Fetch/Offset wasn't there I get all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

- create a CTE that gets the data you want to return
- include a `COUNT(*) OVER()` in there to get the total count of rows
- return just a subset (based on your `OFFSET .. FETCH NEXT`) from the CTE

So your code would look something along those lines:

```
-- CTE definition - call it whatever you like
WITH BaseData AS
(
    SELECT
        -- select all the relevant columns you need
        p.ProductID,
        p.ProductName,
        -- using COUNT(*) OVER() returns the total count over all rows
        TotalCount = COUNT(*) OVER()
    FROM 
        dbo.Products p
)
-- now select from the CTE - using OFFSET/FETCH NEXT, get only those rows you
-- want - but the "TotalCount" column still contains the total count - before 
-- the OFFSET/FETCH
SELECT *
FROM BaseData
ORDER BY ProductID
OFFSET 20 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: So I had a very similar CTE like yours. But how do I set my ```OUTPUT``` parameter ```@TotalRecord```. It doesn't like when I do this: ```SELECT p.ProductName, @TotalRecord = COUNT(*) OVER()```

Comment: @Noonmoon: you can't set the output param - you'll need to return the `TotalCount` column

Comment: How come I can't set the output parameter? Looks like I need to figure out a way to read the column added in EF core...

Answer (score 0):

As a habit, I prefer non-null entries before possible null. I did not reference those in my response below, and limited a working example to just the two inputs you are most concerned with.

I believe there could be some more clean ways to apply your local variables to filter the query results without having to perform an offset. You could return to a temp table or a permanent usage table that cleans itself up and use IDs that aren't returned as a way to set pages. Smoother, with less fuss.

However, I understand that isn't always feasible, and I become frustrated myself with those attempting to solve your use case for you without attempting to answer the question. Quite often there are multiple ways to tackle any issue. Your job is to decide which one is best in your scenario. Our job is to help you figure out the script.

With that said, here's a potential solution using dynamic SQL.
I'm a huge believer in dynamic SQL, and use it extensively for user based table control and ease of ETL mapping control.

```
use TestCatalog;


set nocount on;
--Builds a temp table, just for test purposes
drop table if exists ##TestOffset;
create table ##TestOffset
    (
    Id int identity(1,1)
    , RandomNumber decimal (10,7)
    );

--Inserts 1000 random numbers between 0 and 100
while (select count(*) from ##TestOffset) < 1000
    begin
        insert into ##TestOffset
            (RandomNumber)
        values
            (RAND()*100)
    end;
set nocount off;


go
create procedure dbo.TestOffsetProc
    @StartIndex int = null --I'll reference this like a page number below
    , @RecordsPerPage int = null

as
begin
    declare @MaxRows int = 30; --your front end will probably manage this, but don't trust it. I personally would store this on a table against each display so it can also be returned dynamically with less manual intrusion to this procedure.
    declare @FirstRow int;

    --Quick entry to ensure your record count returned doesn't excede max allowed.
    if @RecordsPerPage is null or @RecordsPerPage > @MaxRows
        begin
            set @RecordsPerPage = @MaxRows
        end;

    --Same here, making sure not to return NULL to your dynamic statement. If null is returned from any variable, the entire statement will become null.
    if @StartIndex is null
        begin
            set @StartIndex = 0
        end;

    set @FirstRow = @StartIndex * @RecordsPerPage

    declare @Sql nvarchar(2000) =   'select
                                        tos.*
                                    from ##TestOffset as tos
                                    order by tos.RandomNumber desc
                                    offset ' + convert(nvarchar,@FirstRow)  + ' rows
                                        fetch next ' + convert(nvarchar,@RecordsPerPage) + ' rows only'

    exec (@Sql);
end


go

exec dbo.TestOffsetProc;
drop table ##TestOffset;
drop procedure dbo.TestOffsetProc;
```